# Using Beautiful Soup to pull the below HTML

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
    data-sort-distance="8.6920742598"
    data-sort-name="Adobe at Arizona Biltmore Country Club"
    data-sort-rating="3.9000000000"
    data-sort-ratings-count="380"
    data-sort-first-review="2012-09-21 00:44:00"
    data-sort-last-review="2016-11-02 17:19:59"
    data-sort-3mi-yoh="-0.327954838709677419354838710"
>
```

Is it possible to use soup.find_all() to pull the Data-sort-XXX values or do i need to run regex to pull the values after the equal sign?

--Update -- Thank you for the quick response. I knew there had to be a way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag `<b class="boldest">`
>   has an attribute “class” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a
>   tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:

```
tag['class']
# u'boldest'
```

> You can access that dictionary directly as .attrs:

```
tag.attrs
# {u'class': u'boldest'}
```

So, in your case you could do a `find_all()` to get the `li` tags and then use `.attrs` to get all the `data-sort-xyz` attributes in a dictionary.